# How to set size and layout in onSizeChanged?

Tags: android, listview, resize, refresh

I can't get my elements, for example `ListView`, to resize properly.

I got a `ListActivity` for searching, with a dashboard, an editbox and a listview. The idea is to hide the actionbar while the keyboard is showing.

I extended `LinearLayout`, to listen to view size changes (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825918/way-to-be-notified-when-the-software-keyboard-is-showing-hiding)) :

```
public class SizeChangingLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {
    //...
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int xNew, int yNew, int xOld, int yOld)
    {        
        View actionbar = mainView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar);

        if (yNew > yOld) 
            actionbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else if (yNew < yOld) 
            actionbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        super.onSizeChanged(xNew, yNew, xOld, yOld);

    }
}
```

The hiding/showing of the actionbar works as expected but there is a gap below the `ListView` of the same height as the hidden actionbar. As soon as any graphics change (e.g. writing in the editbox) the `ListView` fills the gap. A similar behavior appears in reverse, when hiding the keyboard.

[image]

[Edit]

The same problem also appears in changing other layout. Changing `Visibility` of things in `onSizeChanged` shows directly, but changing sizes and margins does not show until some other user action redraws those views. Invalidation does not work from `onSizeChanged`.

[/Edit]

I have tried to refresh the graphics by:

- `invalidate`-ing both the custom
  LinearLayout and the `ListView`  (as
  recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017853/android-how-to-redraw-a-graphic-element))
- `notifyDataSetChanged` on the list's
  adapter
- `forceLayout`

... and more, without success. Why is the `ListView` not resizing at first? Do I have to override `onLayout` in my extended LinearLayout? What have I missed?

Comment: Not any update works, I noticed. "As soon as any graphics change", I wrote. But for example a popup won't make the changes made show. I guess the right elements has to be invalidated, but they don't.

Comment: The problem also appears for all layout changes, for example changing margins of the EditText. But _adding_ layout elements, for example a button to the right of the box, shows immediately though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Adding the following at the end of `onSizeChanged()` will solve it:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        requestLayout();
    }
});
```

See the answer to this question: [Views inside a custom ViewGroup not rendering after a size change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852758/views-inside-a-custom-viewgroup-not-rendering-after-a-size-change)

Comment: View has a post() method, so you don't need to allocate the Handler.

Comment: I was changing the size of child views in `onSizeChanged`, so I had to put the resizing of said child views in the runnable before calling `requestLayout()`

Answer (score 0):

This could be a long shot...

Have you tried playing with the `android:layout_height=""` setting for the `ListView`?

Maybe using `match_parent` or `wrap_content` could force it to work...

As I said... a long shot!

Comment: Just like @PravinCG's suggestion, it does not work. Apparently no layout changes made in `onSizeChanged` on any View is applied until another layout update is made.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the ListView to redraw by changing its height by 1px and calling

`requestLayout()`

Comment: Tried it, and it does not work, unfortunately:

`setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.another_value)));`
`requestLayout();`

It gets the new height only after any other layout changes. Just like in the screenshots of mine. The same behaviour also appears on all Views I try to manipulate in the `onSizeChanged` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do what you want by registering a `setOnFocusChangeListener` and a `setOnClickListener` to the `EditText`.

There are a lot of different scenarios to consider when it comes to navigation and things might need to be changed to work with a certain layout.

Anyway, start by overriding onSizeChanged to show the hidden element when the back button is touched.

```
public class MyLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private MyListActivity mMyListActivity;

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);      
    }

    public void setMyListActivity(MyListActivity mla) {
        mMyListActivity = mla;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // show the element when we get more room       
        if (h > oldh) {
            if (mMyListActivity != null) {
                mMyListActivity.showBar();
            }
        }
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }
}
```

In the ListActivity we grab the MyLinearLayout and pass `this` to it. Then a setOnFocusChangeListener is registered to handle things when the EditText's focus changes. The setOnClickListener is used to hide the element when the EditText already has focus.

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<MyData> mDataList = new ArrayList<MyData>();

    private MyLinearLayout mMyLinearLayout; 
    private LinearLayout mHideMeLinearLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;

    public void showBar() {
        if (mHideMeLinearLayout != null) {
            mHideMeLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get MyLinearLayout and pass this to it.
        mMyLinearLayout = (MyLinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLinearLayout);
        mMyLinearLayout.setMyListActivity(this);

        // the LinearLayout to be hidden
        mHideMeLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutToHide);

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);     
        mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Service.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                if (hasFocus) {
                    imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, 0);
                    mHideMeLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mMyLinearLayout.getWindowToken(), 0);
                    mHideMeLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        mEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mHideMeLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        .....
    }

    .....
}
```

I'll provide a working example later, but gotta run now.