# EditText loses focus after resizing ListView when keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView that I need to manually resize when the keyboard is displayed.

This works by overwriting the onSizeChanged method and changing the size of the view accordingly. (Thanks to this post [How to set size and layout in onSizeChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262265/how-to-set-size-and-layout-in-onsizechanged))

However, when the size of the list view is changed the EditText that I clicked on loses its focus and I can't enter any text.

EDIT:
I tried to set the focus of the EditText that had the focus before, however, this doesn't always work, although the method returns true when calling request focus

Comment: request the focus after the resizing

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Focusable EditText inside ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2679948)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onSizeChanged() after resizing the ListView add this line.

```
 editText.requestFocus();
```

Comment: I don't think this works for the case where there are multiple EditText's, where an arbitrary one could be being edited at the time of the resize event (which is my problem right now)...

Answer (score 0):

Use edittext.requestfocus() method:

```
requestFocus();
```