# How to move my widget up when keyboard open in android

Tags: android, shell

How to move up the widget when keyboard open in when i touch the edit box in full screen mode . 
I have use below code but it didn't work so please help me, i m totally stuck.
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
I have use this code and set in manifest but it not work
Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262265/how-to-set-size-and-layout-in-onsizechanged

Comment: try android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Answer (score 1):

Try giving:

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your manifest.

Comment: well, I always give this for almost every activity of my projects and it works.

Comment: are you giving adjustResize too. Try giving adjustPan alone.